# Read all pages within a domain

Tags: python, scraper

I am using the urllib library to fetch pages. Typically I have the top-level domain name & I wish to extract some information from EVERY page within that domain. Thus, if I have xyz.com, I'd like my code to fetch the data from xyz.com/about etc. Here's what I am using:

```
import urllib,re

htmlFile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.xyz.com/"+r"(.*)")
html = htmlFile.read()
...............
```

This doe not do the trick for me though. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks.
-T

Comment: Use `wget`, the recursive webpage downloader, to download a webpage, and all webpages linked from that webpage, and all webpages linked from *those* webpages, and so on.

Comment: Also, just a note, make sure you are not killing some poor person's website by pulling a ton of data from it.

Comment: Also, @Lattyware, you are right, I mean to do my work responsibly.

Comment: You can find many crawler programs including website downloaders, website scrapers, website analyzers etc. Any reason not using one of those? Is it a requirement you code it yourself or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @zigdon answer I recommend you to take a look at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) framework.

[CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) will help you to implement crawling quite easily.

Comment: This sounds like it is perfect, will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I am finding that using scrapy's BaseSpider is working well for my needs. However, one problem remains: scrapy simply fetches information from the start_url & 1 level below that; any information lying at deeper levels is missed. How do I get my spider to look as far deep as the site might go?

Comment: If you use BaseSpider, you will program your spider manually. You will tell him what page to load, which data to extract and so on. CrawlSpider can extract all links automatically. Read the docs for more information. If you have more specific questions please ask.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you would expect `domain.com/(.*)` to work. You need to have a list of all the pages (dynamic or static) within that domain. Your python program cannot automatically know that. This knowledge you must obtain from elsewhere, either by following links or looking at the sitemap of the website.

As a footnote, scraping is a slightly shady business. Always make sure, no matter what method you employ, that you are not violating any terms and conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a regular expression on the web server. Turns out, web servers don't actually support this kind of format, so it's failing.

To do what you're trying to, you need to implement a spider. A program that will download a page, find all the links within it, and decide which of them to follow. Then, downloads each of those pages, and repeats.

Some things to watch out for - looping, multiple links that end up pointing at the same page, links going outside of the domain, and getting banned from the webserver for spamming it with 1000s of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy has this functionality built in. No recursively getting links.  It asynchronously automatically handles all the heavy lifting for you.  Just specify your domain and search terms and how deep you want it to search in the page .ie the whole site.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: thanks for the heads-up about Scrapy, I had completely overlooked it. @San4ez has a more specific example that i am going to try out first.